# TCP Server/Client: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Tags: python, json, sockets, tcp, multiplayer

I am trying to create a simple multiplayer mode for a little game using python. What I want to do is sharing the position of each player connected to the server. Right now though I am stuck struggling with having even one client communicating with the server, using the socket module and json files (which don't seem to cause problems though).

**The error I get and when:**

As soon as I try to send something via client a second time I get the " [Errno 32] Broken pipe" error. According to some googling this happens when the connection is closed. Unfortunately I don't see where it is getting closed.

Currently my code is pretty much this: http://thomasfischer.biz/python-simple-json-tcp-server-and-client/ . I didn't change much since I immediately ran into this problem.

Server Client:

```
import SocketServer
import json

class MyTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

class MyTCPServerHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        try:
            data = json.loads(self.request.recv(1024).strip())
            print data
        except Exception, e:
            print "Exception wile receiving message: ", e

server = MyTCPServer(('127.0.0.1', 13373), MyTCPServerHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Player Client:

```
import SocketServer
import json

def __init__(self):
    self.S = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.S.connect(('127.0.0.1', 13373))

*lots of game related code*

pos = {'id':id, 'pos': (x, y, z)}
self.S.send(json.dumps(pos))
self.position = (x, y, z)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() #to keep the game running and updating
```

Error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/app/__init__.py", line 123, in run
    event_loop.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/app/base.py", line 135, in run
    self._run_estimated()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/app/base.py", line 164, in _run_estimated
    timeout = self.idle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/app/base.py", line 273, in idle
    redraw_all = self.clock.call_scheduled_functions(dt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/clock.py", line 309, in call_scheduled_functions
    item.func(ts - item.last_ts, *item.args, **item.kwargs)
  File "/home/tim/tools/Pyglet/PlayerClient.py", line 609, in update
    self._update(dt / m)
  File "/home/tim/tools/Pyglet/PlayerClient.py", line 641, in _update
    self.S.send(json.dumps(pos))
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Answer (score 4):

Broken Pipe occurs when one end of the connection tries sending data while the other end has already closed the connection.

```
 self.S.send(json.dumps(pos))
```

When the above is being attempted the server has already closed the connection. Possibly during the `*lots of game related code*` And client side TCP is aware of that.But the client application is not. Check the tcpdump b/w the client and server. You should be seeing FIN or RST from the server.

You need to have mechanism to capture TCP events like FIN/RST in your application code. TCP applications should not be written with out the mechanisms to capture asynchronous TCP events.